# Addrress mapping to Customer,Emloyee and Restaurant

Tags: database-design

I need some suggestion on how to design a Database schema for sharing the Address table among Customer address, Employee address restaurant, and Restaurant itself address. Customer can have multiple address, how can we handle this scenario in a Normalized form.

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We request you to show your effort first, what you have done and tried so far. We can not answer direct question where there are no efforts. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, you need to group all the entities under a common group say 'users' and differentiate them by a separate 'user_types' table.

In your case, there are three 'user_types' -  Customer, Employee, Restaurant

```
id | user_type
--------------
 1 | customer
 2 | employee
 3 | restaurant
```

And in your user table, you can have a foreign key reference through user_type_id column

Create a separate address table with the required address fields
Then you can establish an one-to-many relationship between customer-addresses or employee-addresses or restaurant-addresses through a foreign key reference to user. For example,

```
id|door_no|address_line_1|address_line_2|user_id
----------------------------------------
1 | 21/B  | Baker street |8th avenue    |1
```

This answer might further help you: [One Address Table for Many entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031323/one-address-table-for-many-entities)